# How could I group entries by similar timestamp, not by truncated timestamp in snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Due to not exactly best design that cannot be changed now, I have a bit of a difficult situation. I am logging some resource consumption, think RAM for example, per process/computer in an interval. The interval is not 100% precise however.

The table of event logs may look like this, here I am using hour fractions from some arbitrary moment as an example, not UTC timestamp, which is actually used.

| timestamp | ID of source | ID of system | resource usage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | server 1 | mysystem | 100 |
| 0.01 | server 2 | mysystem | 50 |
| 0.02 | server 3 | mysystem | 10 |
| 7.99 | server 1 | mysystem | 40 |
| 8.01 | server 2 | mysystem | 30 |
| 8.01 | server 3 | mysystem | 20 |

My task is to provide usage for each system, which can have multiple of these servers that independently log their usage. The naive idea I originally implemented was to divide my timestamp by the logging interval and then sum records that have same `timestamp` and `ID of system`. The table above illustrates perfectly why that won't work. If I am logging each 8 hours, but there is slight offset, wrong values will be grouped.

You could think `round()` instead of `floor()` division would help - but different systems have started logging at different times, so there is also constant offset from the 8 hour interval.

What do you propose to group those records, so that I have accurate grouping?

Comment: [TIME_SLICE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/time_slice) could produce buckets of specific length

Comment: @LukaszSzozda I'll try it, but it seems to have the same problem - if I fit the buckets so that one system's logs are in the middle of that bucket, another system might find its logs right at the edge. One thing that occured to me is that I actually need only sum of the latest values - so for each system, whatever timestamp is first found minus 1 minute would work just fine.

Comment: Let me rephrase, you would like to have first value per each system + 8h, miss the gap and get the next group of 8h. Sort of ["session window"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/stream-analytics-query/session-window-azure-stream-analytics)?

Comment: Yes, that would be awesome. But for some stats, the first window would be enough and that would probably be easier. But for graphs that show progress over time, I really need some way to jump over these record groups, even if the time distance is not exactly 8 hrs down to a millisecond. Also, there can be longer gap after restart. It is bad design of logging :(

Comment: Looks like a great use case for [MATCH_RECOGNIZE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/match_recognize), unfortunately it is not possible to use [FIRST](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/match_recognize#limitations-on-window-functions-used-in-define-and-measures) inside define clause in Snowflake. Live demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/iTW2OeiR

Comment: @LukaszSzozda Thanks! That seems to work, once I set the range to something less than the interval, such as `FIRST(timestamp)+7.5`. I will check if it works in snowflake too. https://dbfiddle.uk/DC5vgGmW

Comment: another option is to resample/linearize your data to the intervals you do want, thus if you have CPU temp on fractionial intervals, but really want the estimated temp "on the hour" then the first or the last, is not an a exact fit. Another problem is if you have different count of units, thus you might want average verse sum (aka normailize) your data.